# In Python 3.4, what is best/easiest way to compare paths?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib

Using this code in Python 3.4 and Ubuntu 14.04 do not return `True`

```
import pathlib

path1 = pathlib.Path("/tmp")
path2 = pathlib.Path("/tmp/../tmp")

print(path1 == path2)
# gives False

print(path1 is path2)
# gives False
```

But normally "/tmp" and "/tmp/../tmp" are the same folder. So how to ensure that the comparisons return True?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To compare you should [resolve](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.resolve) the paths first or you can also use [os.path.samefile](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.samefile). Example:

```
print(path1.resolve() == path2.resolve())
# True       

import os
print(os.path.samefile(str(path1), str(path2)))
# True
```

By the way, `path1 is path2` checkes if `path1` is the same object as `path2` rather than comparing actual paths.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using a newer python version than OP: Starting with python 3.5, you can also use `path1.samefile(path2)`, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.samefile).

Comment: This will only work if the paths exist.